# MacBook Pro shows not charging when plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power-management

I've got a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) and as of today it says "not charging" even when it's plugged in.

The MagSafe connector has an orange light, and the power menu's screenshot is attached.

How can I get the battery status to charging?

[image]

Comment: Have you reset SMC @Ian ?

Comment: @ankii I did it and it seemed to work, thanks! Is there any official guidance around this and why it's necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

> If you're experiencing issues with any of these, you might
>   need to reset the SMC.
>
> - Power, including the power button and power to
>     the USB ports
> - Battery and charging
> - Fans and other thermal-management features
> - Indicators or sensors such as status indicator lights (sleep
>     status, battery charging status, and others), the sudden motion
>     sensor, the ambient light sensor, and keyboard backlighting
>     ...

How to reset SMC:

- Shut down your Mac.
- Press and hold all of these keys:

  - Shift (left)
  - Control  (left)
  - Option (Alt)  (left)
- While holding all three keys, press and hold the power button too.
- Keep holding all four keys for 10 seconds.
- Release all keys, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem. It turns out to be charging cable issue.
I suggest to check with `alternate charging cable` and `charger` first.
In my case Apple care replaced the entire logic board but it did not help only until I tested with alternate charging cable.